# Функция random() для double в java

Tags: java

Как использовать функцию `random();` для `double` в `java`?

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте так

```
Random r = new Random();
double randomValue = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();
```

`rangeMax` - максимальное значение

`rangeMin` - минимальное значение

Answer (score 3):

Можно вот так:

```
double a = Math.random() * (MAX_RAND - MIN_RAND) + MIN_RAND;
```

где RAND_MAX, RAND_MIN - максимальное и минимальное требуемые значения соответственно